# Deny all access to Google Cloud SQL appart from App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a PostgreSQL server with a database and a Django app running on Google App Engine. For security reasons I want to allow only the Django app access to the database (i.e only from  the App Engine running the app).
I know I can whitelist a list of IP's but isn't there a role/permission I can grant to the App Engine which allows it to access the database while denying all IPs?

Answer (score 0):

There is the Cloud SQL Client [role](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/project-access-control#roles) that you can use, it fits your use case specially as you are connecting from App Engine.

To restrict the allowed IPs that can connect to your Cloud SQL instance, whitelisting/blacklisting won't be a good idea as App Engine instances are created and destroyed and those are constantly changing their IPs. As such, you can remove the public IP (if it has it) from your Cloud SQL instance so you make it privately accessible only and with the above permission added to App Engine you will be able to reach your database.

You have more info on how to connect to Cloud SQL while using only a private IP [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-ip#connecting_to_an_instance_using_its_private_ip).